# getting a error while deploying the application in Wildfly 8.1. java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: jboss, wildfly-8

I am getting a weird error while deploying my application in Wildfly 8.1 Final

```
11:06:02,660 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
11:06:02,661 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
11:06:02,664 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
11:06:02,673 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-14) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final
11:06:02,686 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-14) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."bpcDAS-PERF.ear".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."bpcDAS-PERF.ear".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "bpcDAS-PERF.ear"
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getBootstrapConfiguration()Ljavax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration;
  at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension.<init>(ValidationExtension.java:121)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.WeldPortableExtensions.tryRegisterExtension(WeldPortableExtensions.java:54)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:121)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:81)
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
  ... 5 more


11:06:22,292 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /C:/wildfly-8.1.0/bin/content/bpcWebServices.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-2.2.7.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:06:22,292 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /C:/wildfly-8.1.0/bin/content/bpcWebServices.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:06:22,293 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-core.jar in /C:/wildfly-8.1.0/bin/content/bpcWebServices.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:06:22,631 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment bpcWebServices.war
11:06:22,650 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."bpcWebServices.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."bpcWebServices.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "bpcWebServices.war"
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getBootstrapConfiguration()Ljavax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration;
  at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension.<init>(ValidationExtension.java:121)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
  at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.WeldPortableExtensions.tryRegisterExtension(WeldPortableExtensions.java:54)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:121)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:81)
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
  ... 5 more
```

Comment: You should probably include some more information here...

Comment: I am using Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}, Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final, jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA, postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc3, slf4j-api and for Javax Validation validation-api-1.1.0.Final. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: maybe jar version conflicts? if you are using maven, make sure that all dependencies that wildfly provides are marked as scope provided